# Sending and receiving data with every key press

Tags: android, sockets, connection

I am developing an app for android but I am not sure where to start with the specific functionality and I hope some of you could point me to the right direction.

Which is the best way to keep updating the view, text field etc. while sending data to the server as well?

*For example if I were pressing the buttom very fast, how could I send the data (lets say the number of how many times I pressed the button) to the server and show to the user on another connection end the number of presses taking place?

Is socket connection a valid option for it?  Is there any other/better solution? Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use http connection but Why? save all click events as log file and then send it for example everyday! anyway you can also use firebase.

Comment: No, thats the point, its not just sending the data, its sending to another user live while clicking the btton